# What is the limit of $v_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x$ be nonnegative real number. The function $f_n$ is defined by:

$$
\begin{align}
f_n : &\mathbb{R}_{+}\mapsto\mathbb{R}\\
  &x\phantom{R}\mapsto 3x^ne^{-x^2}-1.
\end{align}
$$

Let $v_n$ be a real number for all $n>1$ such that :

$$
v_n >1,\;\text{and}\;f_n(v_n)=0.
$$

Calculate the limit of $v_n$, i.e., find $\ell$ that satisfies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}v_n=\ell.$

I tried to do it by contradiction. First, since $v_n>1$, then $\ell\geqslant1$.

Suppose that $\ell$ is not $\infty$. We have $3v_n^ne^{-v_n^2}=1\iff3v_n^n=e^{v_n^2}$.

- If $\ell\neq1$:
  $$3\ell^n=e^{\ell^2}$$
  gives $$\infty=e^{\ell^2}$$
- If $\ell=1$:
  $$3\ell^n=e^{\ell^2}$$
  gives $$3=e$$

So $$\ell=\infty$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it from the definition of a limit being infinite.  First note that for all $n,\ f_n(1)=\frac 3e-1 \gt 0$ and as $x$ gets large $f_n(x) \to -1$, so there is a root in $(1,\infty)$, which is $v_n$.  Also note that for a given $x \gt 1$, $f_n(x)$ is increasing with $n$.  Then convince yourself that there is only one such root by noting $f_n'(1) \gt 0$ and there is only one place where $f'_n(x)=0$, so each $f_n$ rises to a maximum and then falls, crossing the axis, and approaches $-1$.  Now note that given a value for $x$, you can always find an $n$ large enough so that $f_n(x) \gt 0$ by solving $x^n=e^{x^2}, n=\frac {x^2}{\log x}$.  Thus given $x$, you can find $N$ so that for all $n \gt N, v_n \gt x$, so $v_n \to \infty$ with $n$

Answer (score 1):

> If $\ell\neq1$:
>   $$3\ell^n=e^{\ell^2}$$

Sorry, but no. $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n,n) = L$ does not imply that $\lim_{m\to\infty}g(n,m) = L$ or even $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\lim_{m\to\infty}g(n,m)) = L$, which is what you need for your conclusion. But it just doesn't hold in general.

And your demonstration that $1$ is not a solution assumes that $1^\infty = 1$, which is not in general the case.

I suggest using $v_n = 3^{-1/n} e^{v_n^2/n}$, from which you can show that if $v_n$ grows more slowly than $\sqrt n$ - more particularly that $\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n^2/n = 0$, then the limit converges to $1$.

But you still have to show that $v_n$ does indeed grow more slowly than $\sqrt n$.